# Automically make divs in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate divs automatically every few seconds. Right now I have it so I have to click to create divs. How can I make it so that when I load the page my divs are being generated automatically going horizontal until they fill the page? Thank you.

```js
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#child').height() == $('#main').height() && $('#child').width() == $('#main').width()) {
    console.log("done");

  } else {
    $('#child').append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>')
  }
})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {

width:50px;
height:50px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would the functionality be if they resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval to add boxes automatically. And use `display:inline-block;` for `#sub` css style to make it horizontal.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var interval;

interval = setInterval(function(){
  if ($('#child').width() == $('#main').width()) {
    console.log("done");
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    $('#child').append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>')
  }
},1000);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {

width:50px;
height:50px;
background:blue;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#child{ 
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Update 1 :**

You can check the condition dynamically by calculating the number of possible boxes we can have in a container.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var interval;
var counter = 0;
var maxCount = 1000;

interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(counter == 1){
      maxCount = Math.floor($('#main').width()/$('#sub').outerWidth()) * Math.floor($('#main').height()/$('#sub').outerHeight());
    }
    
  if(counter != 0 && counter >= maxCount){
    console.log("done");
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    $('#child').append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>');
  }
  
  counter++;
},1000);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {

width:50px;
height:50px;
background:blue;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#child{ 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: it seems to stop after one row. How can it be so it will continue on to another row and keep going?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `setInterval` function

```js
var interval = setInterval(function(){
if ($('#child').height() == $('#main').height() && $('.row').last().width() == $('#main').width()) {
    console.log("done");
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    var _$row;
    if ($('.row').last().width() == $('#main').width() || $('.row').length == 0){
        _$row = $('<div class="row"></div>');
        $('#child').append(_$row);
    } else {
        _$row = $('.row').last();
    }
    _$row.append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>');
  }
}, 50);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.row {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it only seems to stop after one row? How can it fill up the whole div or body?

Comment: Updated! Review again. CSS classes were added as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, when document is ready, use setTimeout to do stuff every X ms.

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
const seconds = 2;
function fill() {
 if ($('#child').height() == $('#main').height() && $('#child').width() == $('#main').width())
  return;

 $('#child').append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>');
 setTimeout(fill, seconds  * 1000);
}
setTimeout(fill, seconds * 1000);
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {

width:50px;
height:50px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle it, but the quickest method to get from your code to what you've asked for is to use [setTimeout](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)

```js
// no-conflict safe document ready function
jQuery(function($) {
  // call the function to kick things off
  addRowInOneSecond();

  // adding the row is placed inside this function for clarity / maintainability
  function addRowInOneSecond() {
    setTimeout(addRow, 1000);
  }

  function addRow() {
    if ($('#child').height() == $('#main').height() && $('#child').width() == $('#main').width()) {
      console.log("done");
      // stop, don't do anything else
      return;
    }

    // add the row
    $('#child').append('<div id="sub">aaaa</div>')
    // call the function again to add another row
    addRowInOneSecond();
  }
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

#sub {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make use of `setInterval`. This method will execute the function you pass in as the first argument at each interval (until it is cleared).

```js
let i = 0;
const main = document.querySelector('#main');

setInterval(() => {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  var text = document.createTextNode(i++);
  el.setAttribute('id', `sub-${i}`);
  el.setAttribute('class', 'sub');
  el.appendChild(text);
  main.appendChild(el);
}, 2000);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.sub {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It only seems to be going down in one row. How can it be so it will start a new row after a certain amount and going horizontal?